# Eclipse Juno, Mercurial - Icons within my project not dirty

Tags: mercurial, eclipse-juno

I'm using eclipse Juno and Mercurial for my project. My question is, why icon not change to dirty in newBillPayment folder?

[image]

http://www.rorycullen.com/blog/2009/07/guide-to-subclipse-decorator-icons/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check whether you added this folder in SVN ignore list. If it is added then dirty decorator will not be shown.
2. In the picture itself you can see that there is no team decorator([image]) for `newBillPayment` folder. That means it was not added to repository yet. Add it to svn repository and modify the local file and check.

Comment: In the link it shows to sub-eclipse decorator.Any way it doesn’t matter.No change in answer it apply's to mercurial also.